Flowify add on with 3D scan file
I am new to blender but recently gave it a try after coming across a tutorial for the flowify add on and thought it may solve a problem I have had for a while now.
Basically, I want to make a 3d stencil from a 3d scan to be used for painting.
I have imported the .obj scan file into blender but when I try to 'create source grid from target surface', I get an error stating 'this is not a valid grid shaped target surface'
The .obj file will be the target surface.
Is there any way I can make this work? Hope it makes sense.
Any help is appreciated.

It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

There appears to be a YT video for that third-party addon here which tells you where to obtain help if you need it.
